# Python grammar rules for inbound text to variable parsing

Tags: python

Say your input consists of many of this sample templates without any visible delimiter but inline expressions.

```
sample_tmp_1 = """
IKE peer REMOTE.END.RANDOM.IP., Index 1651435, 
Gateway Role: IKE-GATEWAY
REMOTE.END.RANDOM.IP.:500
"""

sample_tmp_2 = """
    IKE peer REMOTE.END.RANDOM.IP., 
    REMOTE.END.RANDOM.IP.:500Index 1651435, 
    Gateway Name: IKE-GATEWAY
"""
```

and you need to parse certain information from dozens of Templates based on an inline expression.
One way I been solving this is on iteration of the variable

```
for line in sample_tmp_1.split("\n"):
    if "Role:" in line:
       Role = do_X(line,'Role')
    if "IKE peer" in line:
       do_Y

and use regular expressions for 
for line in sample_tmp_2.split("\n"):
    if "Role:" in line:
       do_X
    if "IKE peer" in line:
       do_Y

def do_X: 
    return re.search(Parameter, Data)
def do_Y:
    pass
```

templates that might not have the same data structure as then using regex groups will be very inclusive as I will to play a lot in getting the value position.

```
 INBOUND = re.search(".*(show.*)",text)
    if INBOUND:
        key = INBOUND.group(1)
```

However, I can not just think there is no library (similar to what would  Lex sets up the grammar rules consumed by a yacc parser) for parsing data from templates based on expressions in Python directly.

is there any library for assisting in this work?

for example:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> t = Template("Hello {{ something }}!")
>>> t.render(something="World")
```

and be able to search on a Keyword

```
print(Do_X(t.render, Template))
"World"
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: So, what's your question? I couldn't find any question mark there.

Comment: the question is, is there anything similar to  what  Lex sets up the grammar rules consumed by a yacc parser in python ?  Thank you